# How to prevent a rotated div from moving when changing its width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform, css-transforms

I have a reproduction of the issue I'm facing below:

```css
.rect {
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: absolute;

  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;

  animation: 3s linear 0s infinite normal none running widen;
}

@keyframes widen {
  from { width: 300px; }
  to { width: 500px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Notice how as the rectangle gets wider, its position also changes. It is true that the element's programmatic position isn't changing, but visually on the screen it appears it is.

I am only looking to widen it without having it visually appear to move. That is, the right side of the rectangle should simply extrude out an additional 200 pixels. Is this possible?

Looking around, it seems like setting the `transform-origin` from `center` to `top left` accomplishes this effect, but unfortunately my rectangle's origin of rotation *is* around its center. Perhaps the solution is to temporarily set it in some way while the effect is occurring..

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this is to **wrap the grey rectangle div in another div that does the rotating**. That way the width and rotation can be controlled independently.

If other transformations need to be applied as well, this approach gives you control over the *order* the transformations will be applied.

```css
.rect {
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}

.widen {
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: 3s linear 0s infinite normal none running widen;
}

@keyframes widen {
  from {
    width: 300px;
  }
  to {
    width: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rect">
  <div class="widen" />
</div>
```

Comment: This might be promising? Investigating this solution now to see if it'll work for my purposes.

Comment: Glad the idea has potential. I think the main benefit is that you have control over the order transformations are applied

Comment: I'm a bit confused though, because I'm not sure what to set the parent's width and height to. Previously I just had a single width and height, but now it appears I have two? It seems like there's multiple sources of truth here, and I'm having trouble understanding how to reconcile this.

Comment: Do you have any more specifics you can give about your goal?

Comment: I'm developing a very small rectangle editor. In this program users can rotate rectangles (which applies the `transform: rotateZ` to the rectangle div element. Users can also drag a corner to resize the element from that corner. The issue is that currently dragging the corner also moves the element (as described in the original post). This solution looks promising, but currently there's just a single rectangle (which has a width and height). I'm unsure of how to integrate this solution into such a situation.

Comment: You should be able to control the rotation with the outer `div` and then set the width and height on the `inner` div if you give the outer `div` width and height 100%. That way you are only worrying about one width, and it is on the element that is logically being scaled. I edited my example to show this. Does that help at all?

Comment: Looking at your edit now. Posted a follow-up question just in case in the interim https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71865679/how-to-prevent-a-rotated-resize-auto-div-from-moving-when-resizing-it

Comment: The issue with your edit is that my outer div's width and height is not 100%, no? They are in a large container, so I don't think I can set the width and height of the outer div to such a large value.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. You should just be able to remove width and height on the parent

Comment: You might need to use javascript to get the full effect you're going for

Comment: Some JS is fine. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Something like [this codepen](https://codepen.io/daybrush/pen/KKKdLqw) seems to do what you're describing

Comment: Yes!! An excellent find. Thank you

Comment: Oh wait, nevermind. I thought it was all in that codepen, but it seems to use an external library. Unfortunate.. But yeah, that _is_ the effect I'm looking for. But I cannot use a library for just this, as my application is 99.999% done and this is the last remaining issue.

Answer (score 1):

That squish effect is expected, but for this scenario I'd suggest not animating the size properties anyway since it's going to push your natural DOM flow around with if there's other elements. Instead try `scale` transform, see below.

```css
.rect {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: absolute;

  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;

  transform-origin: center left;
  animation: 3s linear widen infinite;
}

/*
@keyframes widen {
  from { width: 300px; }
  to { width: 500px; }
}
*/

@keyframes widen {
  to { transform: rotate(45deg) scaleX(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not animating anything in my actual code. I simply used an animation to demonstrate the problem (to show how the rectangle moves while it's being widened). In my actual code I'm trying to resize rectangles that are rotated around the origin, and having them move while they're being resized is very jarring to the user.

Comment: @RyanPeschel I'd still suggest `transform` over size attributes for several reasons. If you provide a more complete example of the issue with explanation I'm sure we can get you sorted.

Comment: I don't think scale will work, because doing so increases the size from both sides. I'm just trying to have the rectangle get wider from one side. Imagine a program like photoshop. When you grab an edge to resize a rotated rectangle, it doesn't make it wider from both sides. It simply extrudes the size you grabbed from.

Comment: @RyanPeschel that's what `transform-origin` is for. Try me ;)

Comment: See updated answer..

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of `transform-origin` but the issue is my rectangle is indeed rotated around its center, so not sure if that'll work here.

Comment: Sorry dude having trouble visualizing what you mean without an example but I'm pretty confident it's an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is moving because of the angle. If you want it to grow proportionally, add height to the animation.

**Example 1:**

```css
.rect {
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: relative;

  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;

  animation: 3s linear 0s infinite normal none running widen;
}

@keyframes widen {
  from { width: 300px; height: 200px; }
  to { width: 500px; height: 400px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

If we remove the rotation, it won't look like it is moving.

**Example 2:**

```css
.rect {
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: relative;

  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;

  animation: 3s linear 0s infinite normal none running widen;
}

@keyframes widen {
  from { width: 300px; }
  to { width: 500px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```